# Count From Database Reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got a problem when I'm trying to count data inside firebase database. I try change it many times, but I can't still found how to solve this.

[image: this is my database]

```
private  void setupBadge() {

    String key = request.getKey();


    if (key != null) {
        request.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    mCartItemCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();


                    if (textCartItemCount != null) {
                        if (mCartItemCount == 0) {
                            if (textCartItemCount.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                                textCartItemCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        } else {
                            textCartItemCount.setText(Integer.toString(mCartItemCount) + "");
                            if (textCartItemCount.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                                textCartItemCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```

I think maybe the problem come from my database, cause I'm try to get key. But, tell me if this something wrong with my code, cause it's only displaying "0" all the times.

Comment: Hi. what is your `request.child(key)` is?

Comment: do you see that random number in that picture.. "String key = request.getKey();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon me, What I'm understanding is that :
You want to calculate the number of child's in your "History" Node.
Then you can do query like orderbyChild and give "History" as child key.

ValueEventListener  listener = new ValueEventListener......

Then do Query :

DatabaseReference dbReference = ....

Query query = dbReference.orderbyChild("History");

query.addsingleEventListener(listener);

Hope it helps :) Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

**You can give a try like :**

```
 request.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

            for ( DataSnapshot mdataSnapshot  : dataSnapshot)
                 {

                  int count = mdataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                  **// Here count for number for list of items**
                 }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

You can go to firebase realtime database datasnapshot to see further about it or see datasnapshot in response by debuging & resolve your issue.

Comment: yeah thanks.. but i dont want to calculate base on key.. is that possible if im calculating orderbychild?